# solve it but still having error somewhere

Tags: python, python-3.x

A cashier distributes change using the maximum number of five-dollar bills, followed by one-dollar bills. Write a single statement that assigns num_ones with the number of distributed one-dollar bills given amount_to_change. Hint: Use %.

```
Sample output with input: 19
Change for $ 19
3 five dollar bill(s) and 4 one dollar bill(s)
```

this is how i solved it but am still getting error on some part

```
amount_to_change = int(input())

num_fives = amount_to_change // 5

''' Your solution goes here '''
num_ones = 19 % 5
print('Change for $', amount_to_change)
print(num_fives, 'five dollar bill(s) and', num_ones, 'one dollar bill(s)')
```

Comment: What error ? please give it

Answer (score 3):

You may not use a hard-coded `19` , but rather `amount_to_change`, both 5 and 1 dollar bills

```
amount_to_change = int(input("Enter an amount"))

num_fives = amount_to_change // 5
num_ones = amount_to_change % 5

print('Change for $', amount_to_change)
print(num_fives, 'five dollar bill(s) and', num_ones, 'one dollar bill(s)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue is that you hardcoded the amount used to get the number of ones. You can fix this by replacing the `19` with the value the user input. In the code below, I calculate the number of one's by subtracting the number of five's from the total.

```
amount_to_change = int(input())
num_fives = amount_to_change // 5
num_ones = (amount_to_change - (num_fives * 5)) // 1

print('Change for $', amount_to_change)
print(num_fives, 'five dollar bill(s) and', num_ones, 'one dollar bill(s)')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).